# SQL Recursion and pivot to create hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create and apply a hierarchy to customers, where i do not have control over the customer table or its database.

To do this i am creating a separate database that will contain virtual customers and a mapping table.

There are other processes in place that will take the results of this script and apply it to the customers from the uncontrolled Db.

**VirtualCustomer Table** - I have control over this table design.

These 'customers' represent the hierarchy that has to be applied.

```
VirCustID    |    ParentVirCustID    |    Name
2001         |    NULL               |    Vehicle
2002         |    2001               |    Car
2003         |    NULL               |    Tech
2004         |    2003               |    Comms
```

**HierarchyAssignment Table** - I have control over this table design

Using this table as the mechanism to join the customer to the virtual customer. Virtual customer would then have the rest of the hierarchy.

**Importantly** I am mapping CustID to the lowest level of the hierarchy, so need to recurse from the bottom up.

CustID is the ID of a customer outside of this database, and one i cannot control. I also do not need to join on to that table.

```
CustID    |    VirCustID
1001      |    2001
1002      |    2001
1003      |    2003
```

I am trying to get the result:

```
CustID    |    L1ID    |    L1Name    |    L2ID    |    L2Name 
1001      |    2001    |    Vehicle   |    2002    |    Car
1002      |    2001    |    Vehicle   |    2002    |    Car
1003      |    2003    |    Tech      |    2004    |    Comms
1004      |    NULL    |    NULL      |    NULL    |    NULL
```

At the moment I'm only interested in 2 levels, though it's possible i need to increase this, hence using a mapping table. I need to be able to support L*n*ID and Name.

I think I need CTE recursion and perhaps pivot and have attempted a few things i've cobbled together from other Q/A's though nothing has been successful yet.

This is one of the scripts i was playing with. I just don't know where else to start and any pointers would be gratefully received.

```
WITH cp AS 
(
    SELECT  p.VirCustID, p.parentVirCustID, 0 as [level]
    FROM VirtualCustomer as p
    WHERE p.parentVirCustIDis null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p2.VirCustID, p2.parentVirtualId, c.[level]+1
    FROM  VirtualCustomer as p2
    JOIN cp as c on p2.parentVirCustID= c.VirtCustID
)
select * from cp
```

Comment: @DarrenWainwright Does this need to be a single query? Are you able to do this in a stored procedure instead?

Comment: Where does CustID 1004 come from?

Comment: @CombeeBowlin - A single query would be preferred, though I can utilize a sproc in this case too.

Comment: @TheImpaler - That relates to an actual customer on another DB. It will be used by the process that uses the results from this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the desired result in a single query by doing a simple join ( assuming that wherever you're executing this code has access to all the relevant tables ).

Here is a db-fiddle with the desired output:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsdHCRJNcsg7ZpXbgJ7mbS/0

The hierarchy linking is somewhat counter-intuitive, as you are linking "backwards" from parent to child.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT    cust.custid
         ,sq_levelone.vircustid AS l1id
         ,sq_levelone.name      AS l1name
         ,sq_leveltwo.vircustid AS l2id
         ,sq_leveltwo.name      AS l2name
  FROM    sq_sourcesystemcustids  cust
          LEFT JOIN sq_hierarchyassignment hier ON cust.custid = hier.custid
          LEFT JOIN sq_virtualcustomer sq_levelone ON (hier.vircustid = sq_levelone.vircustid)
          LEFT JOIN sq_virtualcustomer sq_leveltwo ON (sq_levelone.vircustid = sq_leveltwo.parentvircustid)
```

Comment: This is a nice and straightforward approach if we don't introduce additional levels. I'm really hoping to be able to use the same script/solution for n-levels. I originally had Level1 and Level2 values on the hierarchyAssignment table negating the need for any joining, but it just isn't future-proof enough for the rate of change in our industry. I also don't need to select from the source customers. I do thank you for the example though!

Comment: You'd need to add DISTINCT, but this still leaves the problem of additional levels.

Comment: @DarrenWainwright No problem at all.  The desired solution is solving for n-levels, understood! Do you want a ragged hierarchy, or a fixed number of levels?

Comment: @Brent - I'd like no fixed number of levels. Thats my ideal solution. cheers!

Comment: @DarrenWainwright so to make sure I've understood, there may be some situations where there are 5 levels, and some where there are 2 levels.  Note that I included the source Customer ID table to meet the use case of CustID 1004 which does not exist in the HierarchyAssignment table.

Comment: @Brent - correct, yes, it's possible there could be a mixed depth of levels.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Brent's answer, since you're looking to do this in a single query, you'd probably end up using his method, but extrapolating it out to the desired number of levels.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.custid, 
            Levelone.vircustid   AS l1id, 
            Levelone.NAME        AS l1name, 
            Leveltwo.vircustid   AS l2id, 
            Leveltwo.NAME        AS l2name, 
            Levelthree.vircustid AS l3id, 
            Levelthree.NAME      AS l3name, 
            Levelfour.vircustid  AS l4id, 
            Levelfour.NAME       AS l4name, 
            Levelfive.vircustid  AS l5id, 
            Levelfive.NAME       AS l5name, 
            Levelsix.vircustid   AS l6id, 
            Levelsix.NAME        AS l6name, 
            Levelseven.vircustid AS l7id, 
            Levelseven.NAME      AS l7name, 
            Leveleight.vircustid AS l8id, 
            Leveleight.NAME      AS l8name, 
            Levelnine.vircustid  AS l9id, 
            Levelnine.NAME       AS l9name, 
            Levelten.vircustid   AS l10id, 
            Levelten.NAME        AS l10name 
FROM   sourcecustomerids c 
   LEFT JOIN hierarchyassignment h 
          ON c.custid = h.custid 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelone 
          ON ( h.vircustid = Levelone.vircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Leveltwo 
          ON ( Levelone.vircustid = Leveltwo.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelthree 
          ON ( Leveltwo.vircustid = Levelthree.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelfour 
          ON ( Levelthree.vircustid = Levelfour.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelfive 
          ON ( Levelfour.vircustid = Levelfive.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelsix 
          ON ( Levelfive.vircustid = Levelsix.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelseven 
          ON ( Levelsix.vircustid = Levelseven.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Leveleight 
          ON ( Levelseven.vircustid = Leveleight.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelnine 
          ON ( Leveleight.vircustid = Levelnine.parentvircustid ) 
   LEFT JOIN virtualcustomer Levelten 
          ON ( Levelnine.vircustid = Levelten.parentvircustid )
```

It should be pretty apparent how to string these together if you need to add or remove extra layers. It takes about 5-10 seconds per layer to add/remove if you use a keyboard for a living :D

If you're comfortable going with a stored procedure approach, you could dynamically create the correct number of levels based on the data, but I don't think that's easily done in a single query. If you're interested in the procedural option I might take a stab at that in a bit.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Combee. I don't need to join on the source customer. I'm trying to achieve the result with just the 2 tables i have control over. Other processes further down the chain will wire them together.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting this an an alternate answer, being that there is still value in leaving the original answer online ( should you choose to go down the path illustrated by Combee ). This answer makes use of both recursion (your initial query, modified) and pivot.

The following code will allow you to build the hierarchy by columns, with a few caveats.
If you wish to extend the number of layers, you still need to code change.  The reason for this is that SQL Server requires the column definition ( if we aren't writing dynamic SQL ). Additionally, the names are not propagated through the result.  You can get these with a function or as a part of a select statement.

To add new levels to your hierarchy ( 10 have been included ), you would add an additional column (ie [11] or [n] in sq_consolidated array and sq_merge array, add the max([n]) as LnID to sq_final.

This answer also depends on you mapping at the lowest level of the hierarchy ( which was a part of the requirements ).

```
WITH
    sq_hierarchylevels AS
        (SELECT    vircustid
                  ,parentvircustid
                  ,name
                  ,1      AS hierlevel
                  ,[name] AS constname
           FROM    virtualcustomer
          WHERE    parentvircustid IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT    i.vircustid
                  ,i.parentvircustid
                  ,i.name
                  ,hierlevel + 1
                  ,hier.constname
           FROM    virtualcustomer  i
                   INNER JOIN sq_hierarchylevels hier ON hier.vircustid = i.parentvircustid),
    sq_consolidated AS
        (SELECT    *
           FROM    sq_hierarchylevels hier
                   PIVOT (max( vircustid )
                         FOR hierlevel
                         IN( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10] )) AS piv
          WHERE    parentvircustid IS NOT NULL),
    sq_merge AS
        (SELECT    orig.vircustid
                  ,orig.parentvircustid
                  ,orig.[name]
                  ,vircustid   AS l1id
                  ,orig.[name] AS l1name
                  ,[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
           FROM    virtualcustomer  orig
                   LEFT JOIN sq_consolidated fills ON (orig.name = fills.constname)
          WHERE    orig.parentvircustid IS NULL),
    sq_final AS
        (SELECT      vircustid
                    ,[name]
                    ,max( l1id ) AS l1id
                    ,max( [2] ) AS l2id
                    ,max( [3] ) AS l3id
                    ,max( [4] ) AS l4id
                    ,max( [5] ) AS l5id
                    ,max( [6] ) AS l6id
                    ,max( [7] ) AS l7id
                    ,max( [8] ) AS l8id
                    ,max( [9] ) AS l9id
                    ,max( [10] ) AS l10id
             FROM    sq_merge
         GROUP BY    vircustid, name)
SELECT      *
    FROM    sq_final
ORDER BY    vircustid
```